# iOS: Custom view with xib

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm missing something important. Not exactly sure what it is.

I have a custom view subclass. I created a xib file to design its layout. I connected four buttons as outlets to the class.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MCQView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn4;
```

I then have

```
#import "MCQView.h"

@implementation MCQView
@synthesize btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MCQView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
            NSLog(@"%@", btn1);

    return self;
}
```

I then add the view to another view controller via: `initWithFrame`.

When I try to log btn1, to see if it exists, it prints null. I assume that its because I haven't initialized it, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that, considering that if I create it as a new button then all of the stuff in the xib will be useless?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edited Response:**

Oh wait, you're trying to initialize the view within your class? Don't do that.

In Interface Builder, set the Class of MCQview.xib in to MCQView to automatically create the connection. The, connect all your buttons, if you haven't already.

Afterwards, you'll be able to edit the properties automatically as you see fit.

[image]

**Original Response**

I'm doing this from memory, but I think you it should be done like this:

```
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MCQView" owner:self options:nil];

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init]; // or if it exists, MCQView *view = [[MCQView alloc] init];

view = (UIView *)[nib objectAtIndex:0]; // or if it exists, (MCQView *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];

[self.view addSubview:view];
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. How do then instantiate that view from another view controller? With the custom xib.

Comment: To instantiate the view in another view controller, use the code under the **Original Response** header.

Comment: Ah, that works. How do I go about initializing the custom view?

Comment: What are you trying to initialize exactly? To set information on the views properties just call them via their accessor methods. As an example, 

`[view.btn1 addTarget...]`

Comment: Why do you create this "UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];"

Comment: 3 years ago, you had to pass in an empty, initialized view. These days, returning nil works, i think.

Answer (score 4):

This should be simple:

```
view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MCQView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift (2):

```
    var nib = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MCQView", owner: self, options: nil)
    view : MCQView = nib[0] as! MCQView
    self.view.addSubview(view)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you don't need to init the buttons with the XIB.  Try using initWithNibName instead of loadNibNamed.

Comment: UIView does not respond to initWithNibName:

Comment: Yea i think thats for view controllers