# Instantiate view with XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a xib created by following guide ([How do I create a custom iOS view class and instantiate multiple copies of it (in IB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251202/how-do-i-create-a-custom-ios-view-class-and-instantiate-multiple-copies-of-it-i/9251254#9251254)) but I have a question:

how can I instantiate if from code?

So what should I write in viewDidLoad instead of

```
self.myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

I know how to instantiate it with storyboard, but I have no idea how to do it from code. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to add `-loadNibNamed` method like following:

Add the following code to your Your_View `init` method:

```
NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Your_nib_name" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *mainView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
[self addSubview:mainView];
```

Refer these two questions here:

[Adding a custom subview (created in a xib) to a view controller's view - What am I doing wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354653/adding-a-custom-subview-created-in-a-xib-to-a-view-controllers-view-what-am)

[iOS: Custom view with xib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927559/ios-custom-view-with-xib)

EDIT:

In your `ViewController.m` file

```
#import CustomView.h   <--- //import your_customView.h file

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CustomView *customView = [[CustomView alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:customView];
}
```

Comment: yep, that's clear. But what should I do in ViewController to add view from nib?

Comment: what is `[CustomView customView]`?

Comment: `customView` will be your method of `CustomView` class in which you have initialized your view. i.e in which you have loaded the nib file of the view. If you are writing that code in `-init`, then simply write `[[CustomView alloc]init];`

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4

```swift
extension UIView {
    class func makeFromNib() -> Self {
        let nibName = String(describing: self)
        let bundle = Bundle(for: self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0]
        return view as! Self
    }
}
```

use

```swift
let myView = MyView.makeFromNib()
let profileView = ProfileView.makeFromNib()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Swift 4 extension that I use:

```
public extension UIView {
    // Load the view for this class from a XIB file
    public func viewFromNibForClass(index : Int = 0) -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[index] as! UIView
    }

    // Load the view for this class from a XIB file and add it
    public func initViewFromNib() {
        let view = viewFromNibForClass()
        addSubview(view)
        //view.frame = bounds  // No Autolayout
        view.constrainToFillSuperview()  // Autolayout helper
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initViewFromNib()
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initViewFromNib()
}
```