# ScrollView is not Scrolling into UIViewController? in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

my scrollview is not scrolling.[image]

Comment: yes, you can create a view programmatically.

Comment: So what's the problem? You definitely can do `[[UIView alloc] initWIthFrame:]` whenever you want and add it to the view hierarchy via `addSubview:` method

Comment: Please tell me any tutorials or demo app?

Comment: update your question with one UI screen that shows your New UIview that you want and also include that some label and check box .

Comment: Can I make Custom SDK of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  Here are two:

1. Use the existing markup language.  Storyboards and Xibs are just XML.  You can generate that XML on the server, download it at run time, and then use [`NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26500269/74815).
2. You can invent some new markup.  That XML format isn't documented, to my knowledge.  It's also really hard to read.  You might decide some simple json describing the view you want is all you need.  So just download json responses and instantiate the views and map the properties.  You can get fancy and use things like [`NSSelectorFromString`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1395294-nsselectorfromstring) to invoke the property setters, etc.